# Aerodynamical forces - downforce

Tags: automotive-engineering, aerodynamics

I have heard that car weight (for more friction = more stability and higher traction) is being increased when driving by a force called aerodynamic down-force which causes additional force on the car to push it (increasing the load on wheel), but at the same time doesn't increase car's weight (meaning that car can accelerate faster due to this force as it can exceed more force (according to equation $F_\mathrm{traction} = W\mu$)).

What I want to find out is how to calculate the **increase of load** due to down-force. I don't need to calculate a force applied on car, but rather calculate, how much does load increase on each wheel due to down-force.

Basically, I need to know:

- What constant values do I need to know.
- What are the equations.
- How to correctly split the down-force between wheels, or is it the same on all wheels?.

Comment: This is going to be very complicated. It is not as simple as single equation. Aerodynamic forces are typically calculated using very complicated fluid dynamics models. You haven't mentioned how exact of an answer you want.

Comment: I don't need much of complexity. This is for a simulation in game.
What I need is simplified(but still quite accurate) equation that uses things like:
$V$ - speed
$C_\mathrm{somethin}$ - coefficients
etc. etc.
But not any advanced claculations. I must also know where to find needed constants(and also how they change in different temperatures or when, for example, rear wing is rotated for braking in curve).
So I guess you get the idea;)

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am sorry! I don't understand what's exactly wrong there. I can edit, of course, but I still don't get where's the problem... Oh, possibly it's because my native language is not English so my English is based on the English that I face with in my life...

Comment: @AdriansNetlis - Common, spoken vernacular has always been different than written word, regardless of language.  While StackExchange guidelines don't expect perfect formatting and grammar, there is still an expectation to write posts more formally than a conversation with your friends.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - Last I checked, you have [earned editing privileges on the site](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) and could have easily resolved your concerns yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Very broadly speaking aerodynamic downforce will be proportional to the square of speed relative to the surrounding air.

Although downforce effectively increases weight without increasing mass (in the sense of F=ma) it will increase drag, also broadly in proportion to the square of speed.

The common principal aerodynamic elements of a car are a front wing, rear wing and diffuser (which creates downforce under the car by [ground effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_(cars))). Ride height both overall and front to rear rake angle is very important in the function of the diffuser and undertray which has knock on effects for the suspension geometry.

These forces will act at their respective centres of pressure and balancing them relative to the centre of mass and dynamic loads on the car is a crucial aspect of performance.

As well as the forces directly produced by the wings themselves all of the bodywork will have an interrelated role in directing and controlling the airflow in open wheeled card the front wing is especially important in this respect. Similarly it is also essential to provide airflow for cooling or radiators, brakes ets as well as engine induction.

Comment: Hm... I don't wanna get too much into complexivity, what I want mostly is explained equations. Can you, please, get any?:)

Comment: The simplest way would be to model downforce as a single force acting downwards at a point which can be adjusted front to rear, where the force is v squared times some coefficient of proportionality.Similarly for drag.

Comment: OK! And, possibly, multiplied with air density. However, I really can't apply this as force(if I did, it would only push down on suspension, but not increase traction). That means that I need to calculate where it acts and due to that position adjust wheel load. I need to calculate it's distribution. Would it be possible to do it using CG of car? Oh, and also - where cold I find realistic coefficient values for this? Just like drag coefficient, but for downforce.

Comment: Maybe I need to somehow obtain coefficient of downforce for each wheel? It's that front wing would apply to front wheels, rear wing - to rear wheels, sideskirts - to all of them. So obtain the coefficient at specific position and add $V^2C_\mathrm{downforce}\rho$ to the wheel's load... In this case I need to know some stock values for some of cars aswell as how to calculate kind of accurate coefficients(so that I can create accurate tunings0.

Comment: Downforce is transferred to the wheels through the suspension so you can treat it in the same way that you do the weight force arising from the mass of the vehicle. You could treat is as an additional centre of mass which has weight but not inertia.

Comment: May I do it like this?  
$F_{down-force} = L_{o} / L * m * g * V2 * C_{drag}$
?
Or do I need something more?